# Lysol and bleach

Tags: home-experiment, safety

I mixed Lysol with bleach and observed that the container became very hot. What reaction occurs between Lysol and bleach, and could it be dangerous or explosive?

Comment: I would dispose of it in the cleanest way possible. Keep any fumes away from you and go to the doctor if you start feeling very sick. This may be of some use http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/295/what-happens-when-you-mix-lysol-and-bleach

Comment: This question should stay open. It is not `unclear what you're asking`. The OP wants to know if $$\ce{Lysol + bleach->bad}$$ We can answer this pretty definitively, and the link to the Skeptics.SE post will help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because we have no way to know the particulars of "the" container that the OP mixed and whether or not it will really cause an explosion or injury.  As such, as currently worded this is an off-topic medical question.

Comment: Rewording it to be about the _general_ results of mixing lysol and bleach, not about any specific container of lysol and bleach, would make it (IMO) on topic.

Comment: You have to add the components of you lysol if you want help

Answer (score 4):

I guess it is due to the hydrogen peroxide content in Lysol and of hypochlorite in bleach.
If I'm right, what is going on is a reaction like:

$$\ce{OCl^- + H2O2 -> O2 + H2O + Cl^-}$$

Be careful: oxygen enhances fire.

Anyway, being hypochlorite an oxidizing agent, some other reactions could be happening: it would still be safe not to mix them.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers it would be worth including a clear outline of the key ingredients in Lysol and bleach. We can work it out but it would be better to state it clearly for the record.